# Type 'exceptions.ValueError'

Tags: python

I get a Value error when trying to iterate over the following lists, with this code:

```
for (row,num) in (cur.fetchall(),range(1,cur.rowcount+1)):
```

lists:

```
(((2L, 0L, 'You must install a MySQL driver before doing anything. UNlike PHP, only the SQLLite driver is installed by'), (3L, 0L, "default with Python. The most used package to do so is MySQLdb but it's hard to install it using"), (4L, 0L, 'easy_install'), (24L, 0L, ' eine Nachricht '), (25L, 0L, ' Das ging ja schnell '), (27L, 0L, ' Noch ein dicker Hund! ')), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

The first list is a list containing tuples by itself, the second one is a range of numbers.

Can you explain to me, why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zip` it!

```
 for (row,num) in zip(cur.fetchall(),range(1,cur.rowcount+1)):
```

Answer (score 3):

Written as you have it, the thing you're iterating over must yield 2-tuples<sup>1</sup>.  However, what you have first yields the `cursor.fetchall` results and then the row count list which aren't length 2 iterables ...

You'd need to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them together for it to work out correctly:

```
for (row,num) in zip(cur.fetchall(),range(1,cur.rowcount+1)):
```

With that said, python has a builtin function for this called [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for num, row in enumerate(cur.fetchall(), 1):
```

Batteries included I guess . . .

<sup><sup>1</sup>actually, any 2 item iterable can be unpacked.  It doesn't *have* to be a tuple</sup>